# Accessing devise helper 'user_signed_in?'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, helper

I'm unable to use 'user_signed_in?' in my application controller, and wondered if anyone knew how to fix it.

It's works fine in my views, but in my application controller i get

```
NoMethodError in PostsController#index
undefined method `user_signed_in?' for ApplicationController:Class
```

A lot of people had this problem on rail 3.0.3, but I'm using rails 2.3.8. The suggested fix was 
to use devise_for :user in your routes.rb but that resulted in

```
Internal Server Error
undefined method `devise_for' for main:Object
```

Help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the devise gem installed?

Comment: I believe so, I'm able to do most other devise related things, ie sign up to my app. thx

Answer (score 1):

I use devise with 2.38
How about having

```
==> application_controller.rb <==
protected
 def authorize
   unless User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
    session[:original_uri] = request.request_uri
    flash[:notice] = "Please Log In!"
    redirect_to :controller => 'admin', :action => 'login'
   end
 end
end
```

then each controller, e.g. food_items:

```
 class FoodItemsController < ApplicationController
 before_filter :authorize, :except => [:index, :show] # For all methods except these...

 # GET /food_items
```

slightly different approach.  Might help.

Comment: Thanks Michael - looks good.  Let me try it out tonight when i get back.